# Stream to MongoDB in NodeJS

Tags: node.js, mongodb, stream

I'm using node.js with module streamToMongoDB to stream from a Web API to MongoDB.

```
var streamToMongoDB = require("stream-to-mongo-db").streamToMongoDB;
var JSONStream      = require("JSONStream");
var request         = require("request");
var fs              = require("fs");

// where the data will end up 
var outputDBConfig = { dbURL : "mongodb://user:password@0.0.0.0/test", collection : "temperature" };

// create the writable stream 
var writableStream = streamToMongoDB(outputDBConfig);

// create readable stream and consume it 
request("http://0.0.0.0:8081/getTemp")
    .pipe(JSONStream.parse('*'))
    .pipe(writableStream);
```

But I'm fetching follwing error:

```
Unhandled rejection TypeError: Cannot read property 'close' of undefined
    at Writable.<anonymous> (C:\Users\User\node_modules\stream-to-mongo-db\out\index.js:98:16)
    at tryBlock (C:\Users\User\node_modules\asyncawait\src\async\fiberManager.js:39:33)
    at runInFiber (C:\Users\User\node_modules\asyncawait\src\async\fiberManager.js:26:9)
```

I aslo tried to stream a local json file to the mongdb with the same result.

Comment: You should "break this down in parts". i.e 1. Try to connect to MongoDB alone with your credentials. 2. Try and create an output stream of plain JavaScript objects from a JSON source. One of those things is your problem and testing individually will highlight the problem. If both of those work fine then the problem is with the selected module. So don't use it and do something else.